# Reliably hide Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm using `Bootstrap` 2.3.2, and I'm using modal dialogs like this:

```
<div id="notice1" class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <h4>This is a dialog for user...</h4>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

and

```
var notice1 = $("#notice1");
notice1.modal({
    keyboard: false,
    backdrop: "static",
    show: false
});

// Show the dialog
notice1.modal("show");

// Close the dialog
notice1.modal("hide");
```

Most of the the time, the above works fine and the modal dialog are opened and closed programmatically. However, in some rare cases, calling `.modal("hide")` does not close the dialog at all though the dark backdrop is removed.

This is a huge potential issue because the dialog may get stuck on the screen and block part of the content.

Is there a reliable way to ensure the dialog is always closed after calling `.modal("hide")`? Or better yet, how do we ensure a consistent `hide` behavior from `Bootstrap`? I don't want to remove the dialog completely from the DOM, because the same dialog may be re-used on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals

You can catch the `hidden` event and force the `display:none` property.

```
    notice1.on('hidden', function () {
      $(this).css("display", "none")
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

You can hide the modal by using the following code.

```
 $("#notice1").hide();
 $(".modal-backdrop").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using 1.9.x, below code working..

```js
$("#yourModalWindow").modal('hide');
```